# How to combine natural join and left outer join in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables students, enrollments, and classes.  I want to list every student and the department code of each class they have taken (department code is in classes) *including* the students who have not taken any classes (department code would be blank in this case).  This is necessary because of future computations that will be done.

Here is how I've thought about this.  The following query does a left join of students and enrollments so that I include students who have not enrolled in any classes

```
select s.B#, s.firstname, e.classid
from students s, enrollments e 
where s.B#=e.B#(+)
```

This query works as expected.

Next, I join enrollments and classes so that I can see the corresponding dept_code for each enrollment:

```
select B#, dept_code
from enrollments natural join classes
```

This is also working as expected.

When I try to bring the two together though I run into problems

```
select s.B#, s.firstname, dept_code
from students s, (enrollments e natural join classes)
where s.B# = e.B#(+)
```

Attempting to run this query I get the error:

```
ORA-25156: old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins
```

Can anyone please explain what's going on here?

Comment: Even Oracle recommends to stop using the `(+)` outer join syntax

Answer (score 1):

You will be better off using explicit `JOIN` instead of old-style comma-separated joins with where clause. Same goes here for `(+)`.

Write your query like that instead:

```
select s.B#, s.firstname, dept_code
from students s
left join (
select * -- if there are same names of columns in both tables, specify them explicitly
from enrollments e
join classes c on e.? = c.? -- specify here your natural join columns
) e on s.B# = e.B#
```

Btw, the error tells you exactly that you can't combine old style joins with ANSI joins. Probably time to switch to the newer format which exists for a long time now.

Comment: This is not answering the requirement. The Inner join interrupts with the left join

Comment: Left join won't work (see my comment to Gordon). Sub-query is not necessary (see my answer)

Comment: Lmao, I'm a bit sleepy. Didn't mean a subquery, rather a derived table :)

Comment: Same answer... :-)

Comment: Well you basically pointed me out, so I just rewrited it without looking at yours :)

Answer (score 1):

the brackets are not really needed, I put them there just to emphasize the structure

```
select      s.B#, s.firstname, c.dept_code
from                    students    s 
            left join   (           enrollments e
                        join        classes     c
                        on          c.classId = e.classId
                        )
            on s.B# = e.B3 
;
```

Might as well be written like this (only a different format)

```
select      s.B#, s.firstname, c.dept_code
from                    students    s 
            left join   enrollments e
            join        classes     c
            on          c.classId = e.classId
            on          s.B# = e.B3 
;
```

---

P.s.
If you have doubt about this syntax, you might want to try this:

```
create table t1 (i int);
create table t2 (i int);
create table t3 (i int);
create table t4 (i int);
create table t5 (i int);
```

---

```
insert into t1 (i) values (1);
insert into t2 (i) values (1);
insert into t3 (i) values (1);
insert into t4 (i) values (1);
insert into t5 (i) values (1);
```

---

```
select  *
from            t1
        join    t2
        join    t3
        join    t4
        join    t5
        on      t5.i=t4.i
        on      t4.i=t3.i
        on      t3.i=t2.i
        on      t2.i=t1.i
;
```

Comment: You need to specify `ON` clause for every join, not at the end of the query. It would yield an error, AFAIK

Comment: You'll be surprised.

Comment: Well, if it works in Oracle then it's good to know and I'm mistaken. That wouldn't compile in Postgres.

Comment: Yes it would :-) This is a standard syntax

Comment: Good to know! Thanks. Though, I'd still rather stick with typing it right away for readability.

Comment: This syntax is great exactly for the requirement raised in this post. For all other purposes I prefer the conventional syntax. good night :-)

Comment: @KamilG. that is standard SQL and works in Postgres, Oracle, SQL Server, even MySQL. It's not always possible to rewrite a query with the ON immediately after its respective JOIN. Or rather, it is but that often means mixing LEFT and RIGHT joins and that's even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look something like this:

```
select s.B#, s.firstname, c.dept_code
from students s left join
     enrollments e
     on s.B# = e.B3 left join
     classes c
     on e.classId = b.classId;  -- I am guessing what the `JOIN` column is
```

In other words, you need two `left join`s to keep all the students.  Otherwise, the `on` clause might filter rows out.

I also strongly encourage you to avoid and un-learn `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is just a bug waiting to happen in code.  It matches columns only based on their names -- not even taking into account declared foreign key relationships.

It hides the columns being joins, which makes debugging and understanding queries much more difficult.  For instance, because tables I create almost always have columns such as `CreatedAt` and `CreatedBy`, it can't be used.

EDIT:  (For `lgrade`)

You would put the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
select s.B#, s.firstname, c.dept_code
from students s left join
     enrollments e
     on s.B# = e.B3 and e.lgrade is not null left join
     classes c
     on e.classId = b.classId;  -- I am guessing what the `JOIN` column is
```

Comment: In enrollments there is also an lgrade field (letter grade).  How could I adapt your approach to only include enrollments where lgrade is not null?  I attempted to put "where lgrade is not null" at the end however the problem with that is it deletes all the students we added in that have not enrolled in classes because grades for students fitting that description would be null. I only wish to not include rows in the enrollments table where the lgrade was left null.

Comment: Not equal to the original query. first left join might be matched while the second might not.Eliminating the Nulls requires some work since the first left join may cause duplications of rows from the base table.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly encourage you to avoid and un-learn outer join because it produces nulls. Having nulls is just a bug waiting to happen in code. Outer join isn't really a join at all, rather a 'unnatural' union, using nulls to force things together.

Suggested alternative approach: do the union yourself using an appropriate default value:

```
select B#, firstname, dept_code
  from students 
       natural join enrollments
       natural join classes
union
select B#, firstname, '{{NONE}}' as dept_code
  from students
 where B# not in ( select B# from enrollments );
```